# How to fill out a form with many rows with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill out a form with more than *250 rows*, and the only way I could achieve it was by iterating row by row of my *dataframe*, but the problem I have is that for some reason, the page throws me an alert with the legend

> "the session has expired, reconnect."

Then my question is: *Is it possible to fill out a form with many rows and take less time than iterating row by row?*

My code:

```
#read data
df = pd.read_excel('pre_data.xlsx')
for index,row in df.iterrows():

    X = index + 1

    time.sleep(.3)
    #fill inputs by css_selector
    WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,f'#detalle_codigo_articulo{X}'))).send_keys(row['codigo'])

    desc = row['descripcion']+'\n'+row['composicion']
    WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,f'#detalle_descripcion{X}'))).send_keys(desc)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,f'#detalle_cantidad{X}'))).send_keys(row['cantidad'])
    WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,f'#detalle_precio{X}'))).send_keys(str(row['precio']))

    if index != len(df) -1 :
        browser.execute_script('''document.querySelector('#detalles_datos > input[type=button]').click()''')
    UNIDAD = [i for i in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('option') if i.text.strip() =='unidades']
    UNIDAD[index].click()
```

The if is to click on the "Agregar línea descripción" button. He adds one more row to the form. If you are in the last lap of the loop, you will not add, since empty rows are not allowed

This is the form view:

[image]

Comment: `iterrows()` is slow as hell, so that probably explains it. There has to be a better way to do this though, no?

Comment: Yes, I try to use threads but the problem is that the `CSS_SELECTOR` is handled by the index

Comment: How long does it take until you get that session expiry message? Is this a publicly available website?

Comment: in five minutes, I already got a solution..

Comment: Oh great, what worked?

Comment: Yep, I could make you select all dropdownlists in a single expression and at the moment it has not failed

Comment: The website is public but for billing use of companies in the country